# How would you check whether or not a username is available in Flutter regarding Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
// Checks for username in our registration authentication.
Future<bool> usernameCheck(String username) async {
  final result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .where('username', isEqualTo: username)
      .get();
  return result.docs.isEmpty;
}
```

This is my function I created to check usernames in Firebase's Firestore database. This function checks to see if a username is available in the database. In the function below, I convert the username to a text string since signupNameController is the textfield for usernames. It doesn't seem to work as exactly as expected.

```
 onPressed: () async {

                      if (usernameCheck(signupNameController.text) == true) {

                        showInSnackBar('Username exists. Please try again');

                      } else if (usernameCheck(signupNameController.text) == false) {

                        if (signupPasswordController.text != signupConfirmPasswordController.text) {
                          showInSnackBar("Passwords don't match.");
                        } else if (signupEmailController.text == ' ' ||
                            signupPasswordController.text == ' ' ||
                            signupNameController.text == ' ' ||
                            signupConfirmPasswordController.text == '') {

                          showInSnackBar("Please fill out all the required information.");

                        } else {


                          try {
                            UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: signupEmailController.text,
                              password: signupPasswordController.text,

                            );

                            // Our Database collection.
                            // This will go directly into our Firestore NoSQL database
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc().set({
                              'username': signupNameController.text.toLowerCase(),
                              'email': signupEmailController.text,
                              'password': signupPasswordController.text,
                              'retypePassword': signupConfirmPasswordController.text
                            });

                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TabNavigation()));


                          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {

                            if (e.code == 'weak-password') {

                              showInSnackBar("The password provided is too weak");

                            } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {

                              showInSnackBar("The account already exists for that email.");

                            }

                          } catch (e) {
                            showInSnackBar(e.toString());
                          }

                        }

                      }
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish. It doesn't seem to work or input a user. What are some ways to solve this? I am using Flutter and using Firebase for the backend side.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly

Comment: If taken, the sign up page is supposed to let the user know with the snackbar command. If it isn't taken, it should be saved to the database and allow the user to sign up with it.

Comment: use await  if (await (usernameCheck()))...

Comment: in the start of onTap method store the value from usernameCheck to a bool variable like bool usernameAvailable = await usernameCheck () and use it in if conditions

Comment: It keeps saying that a username exists. Even if I type up a random username that isn't in the database.

Comment: Because you are not awaiting for the future usernameCheck

Comment: I also want to thank you for your help on this! i have typed await as well and it still gives me this problem.

Comment: you should return !(result.docs.isEmpty) or results.docs.isNotEmpty usernameCheck according to your if else logic

Comment: I just solved it. Turns out I switched the true and false in the wrong way in my if-else statements. I appreciate your help! Thank you for everything!

Comment: Could you please share your solution as an answer, it can be useful for other users.